# Bind SC Images in Sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I'm having a repeater control and want to bind Images to the sc control for `onitemdatabound` event.

My markup is:

```
<sc:Link runat="server" ID="sclnk" Field="#" rel="iframe-960-540">
<sc:image id="scimage" runat="Server" field="#">
</sc:image>
</sc:Link>
```

And my code is:

```
Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Link scBannerLink = e.Item.FindControl("sclnk") as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Link;
if (scBannerLink != null)
{
    scBannerLink.DataBind(promoItem.ID.ToString(), promoItem.PromoLink.Field.InnerField.Name);

}
Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Image scPromoImage = e.Item.FindControl("scimage") as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Image;

if (scPromoImage != null)
{
    scPromoImage.DataBind(promoItem.ID.ToString(), promoItem.PromoImage.Field.InnerField.Name);
}
```

I'm not getting any error but not diaplaying images

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the Databind method of the control to set the properties.

The easier solution is to specify the `Fieldname` and set the `Item` in your repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptImages">
  <ItemTemplate>

        <sc:Link runat="server" ID="scLnk" Field="MyLinkFieldName" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>" Parameters="rel=iframe-960-540">
            <sc:image id="scImage" runat="Server" Field="MyImageFieldName" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>" />
        </sc:Link>

  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And you can pass in the additional attributes in the `Parameters` field on the control as a URL encoded parameters string, e.g.  Parameters="rel=iframe-960-540&param2=value2&param3=value3"

And your code behind binding the control should be:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rptImages.DataSource = Sitecore.Context.Item.GetChildren(); // this needs to be changed to whatever your query is...
    rptImages.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I have a youtube link when I'm trying this it is not showing that image @jammykam

Comment: Are they showing separately? E.g if you just show the image or just show the link?

Comment: No they aren't showing anything.If I was using which I have posted as a question it is showing me 2 more images, while this is isn't

Comment: OK understood. I'd need to see more of your code. Did you change the datasource to whatever your query should be? But just setting the Parameters field on your original code should work then.

Comment: I got it, I have changed my datasource. But it is displaying server tags

Comment: That's strange, working fine for me. Both the link and the image? You could try with a capital Image, but looks good to me...